# Java is unable to retrieve calculated floating point data from SQL query in Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement, sqldatatypes

SQL Code for the view :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "DAC"."W_ETL_RUN_STEP_AVG_TIME" ("NAME", "COUNT", "DURATION_STEP")
AS
SELECT
  step_name                                 AS name,
  COUNT(
      *)                                    AS COUNT,
  --sucess_rows     AS sucess_rows,
  ROUND(SUM(60 * 24 * (to_date(end_ts, 'yyyy-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') - to_date(
      start_ts, 'yyyy-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')))) AS duration_step
FROM w_etl_run_step
WHERE step_name IN
      (SELECT DISTINCT step_name
       FROM w_etl_run_step
      )
      AND start_ts > SYSDATE - 30 --ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1)
--AND status   ='Completed'
GROUP BY step_name
ORDER BY step_name DESC;
```

Which is generating the below data

```
NAME                                     COUNT  DURATION_STEP
wf_retrieving_first_last_records         99       44
wf_move_halp_part_data                   99       45
wf_flat_files_remove_footer              97       41
wf_etl_huge_data_transformation          31       140
wf_Test_Mapping1                         101      45
wf_Split_Non_Key_Columns                 99       45
wf_Separating_duplicate_non_duplicate_rows  99    45
wf_Multiple_Column_To_One_Column           99     44
```

But when i am trying to retrieve this data via java using the below code

```
try {

        String selectSQL="Select name, duration_step from W_ETL_RUN_STEP_AVG_TIME";  //Get last update time 
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);   
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        int  duration_step=0;

        String step_name ="";
        while (rs.next()) {

            step_name=rs.getString("name");

            duration_step=rs.getInt("duration_step");

            System.out.println("Step Name : "+step_name+"         Duration: "+duration_step);

        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }
```

I am getting the following output :

```
Step Name : wf_retrieving_first_last_records         Duration: 0
Step Name : wf_move_halp_part_data         Duration: 0
Step Name : wf_flat_files_remove_footer         Duration: 0
Step Name : wf_etl_huge_data_transformation         Duration: 0
Step Name : wf_Test_Mapping1         Duration: 0
Step Name : wf_Split_Non_Key_Columns         Duration: 0
Step Name : wf_Separating_duplicate_non_duplicate_rows         Duration: 0
Step Name : wf_Multiple_Column_To_One_Column         Duration: 0
```

`Step Name` is printed properly but not the duration which is a calculated value.

Please help.

Comment: Check the data in the database. If it returns 0 the value of the column duration_step is 0 on the database

Comment: please format your question properly

Comment: can you just print the vlaue `rs.getString("duration_step");` and see what it prints

Comment: Hi Ali786, i have tried to print by rs.getString("duration_step"); But it is still giving me the same, zero.

Comment: then check the resultset of this query once by executing it in sql editor`Select name, duration_step from W_ETL_RUN_STEP_AVG_TIME`

Comment: In SQl developer i wrote the same query, and it is giving me perfect result, i am not able to under stand why i am getting this in java.  Please suggest.

Comment: What are the data types of the `W_ETL_RUN_STEP.START_TS` and `W_ETL_RUN_STEP.END_TS` fields in the database? Thanks.

Comment: Try `rs.getString("DURATION_STEP")` instead of `rs.getString("duration_step")`. All object and column names in Oracle are UPPER_CASE by default unless quoted. Best of luck.

Comment: Hi Bob Jarvis, Data types of the W_ETL_RUN_STEP.START_TS and W_ETL_RUN_STEP.END_TS is Date. Thanks for your suggestion. It empowers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. There was problem with the calculation I did for the view (for the difference between two dates in minutes).

Earlier Version:

```
ROUND(SUM(60 * 24 * (to_date(end_ts, 'yyyy-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') - to_date(
  start_ts, 'yyyy-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')))) AS duration_step
```

New Version:

```
ROUND(SUM(60*24*(end_ts-start_ts))) AS duration_step,
```

which is giving me same result on SQL Developer and in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to store float in an int variable, populated by a `getInt` call.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, i have tried with float, String everything but it is still giving me the same result. Please suggest.